# Это не решило мою проблему, но куда деваться, нужно нажать кнопку

Tags: предложение, локализация

Предлагаю название кнопки "Это решило мою проблему!" заменить на "Да, эти вопросы похожи" или на что-то подобное, так как суть кнопки как раз в том, что автор соглашается с тем, что подобный вопрос уже есть в системе, а не в том, что ответ на тот вопрос решил поставленную задачу, так как ответа может и не быть вовсе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похожий вопрос на [SE.meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189782/meta-duplicates-dont-require-an-answer-dont-suggest-there-is-one-when-thats). И, кстати, почему кнопку ещё не нажали? :)

Comment: Нужно удостовериться, что все неточности зафиксированы для данной ситуации, а то потом снимков сделать будет затруднительно.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как проверить, не является ли вопрос дубликатом?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3989/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Нет, заменять не следует. Как раз не имеет значения насколько вопросы *выглядят* похоже. Важно только, имеют ли они всегда одно и то же *решение*—являются ли они *точными* дубликатами (суть вопросов не просто похожа—она одинакова).

Акцент обязан быть именно на решении, поэтому уже система не позволяет пометить вопрос как оригинал, если у него [нет ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) <sub>(потестировал, при попытке закрытия, используя оригинал без ответа на основном сайте (не на Мете), получил: *«Данный вопрос не имеет ответа, получившего голос за или против»*).</sub>

Конечно, разные люди один и тот же вопрос могут по разному воспринимать. Если ответ из указанного вопроса не решил вашу проблему, то отредактируйте ваш вопрос и объясните почему: как уже предложено в интерфейсе.

Если правка заметно изменит суть вопроса: превратит верные до правки вопроса ответы в неотносящиеся к делу, то лучше новый вопрос задать.

---

Если у вас случай когда вы думаете что вопросы идентичны, но существующий ответ для другого вопроса не работает для вас, то НЕ следует нажимать кнопку «Это решило мою проблему!», потому что это не решило проблему (очевидно).

Следует выбрать вторую опцию и подробно изложить почему опубликованный ответ не работает для вас и/или уточнить вопрос так, чтобы ошибочный ответ меньше шансов имел (если он вызван неоднозначностью формулировки оригинала).

Если вас смущает, что надпись говорит «Нет, мой вопрос о другом», когда *вы думаете что вопрос о том же самом*. Тогда спросите себя, чтобы вы сделали, если сами бы предложенный вопрос-дубликат нашли, *до того* как вы свой вопрос задали?

- вы могли бы поставить минус ответу на этот вопрос (не полезен для вас)—вы и сейчас это можете сделать
- вы могли бы оставить комментарий, указав *конкретно* что не работает. Пожалуйста, не оставляйте комментарии, которые просто говорят: "это не работает" (если вы думаете что ошибка в компиляторе, то ошибка скорее всего в вашем коде): старайтесь описывать ошибку так, чтобы другие люди могли её воспроизвести—вы и сейчас это можете сделать
- вы можете "начать конкурс", чтобы привлечь внимание к существующему вопросу—вы и сейчас это можете сделать
- вы могли бы создать новый более качественный вопрос, не пытаясь ужать в комментарии подробности вашего случая—вы сейчас уже это сделали.

Начали ли вы со своего вопроса, позже найдя возможный дубликат, или начав с вопроса дубликата—конечный результат выглядит очень похоже.

Ситуация, когда человек голосует за закрытие вопроса, когда оригинал не имеет адекватного ответа должна быть достаточно редка. В отличие от других причин закрытия, определение является ли вопрос точным дубликатом требует хорошее знание предметной области. Только люди способные ответить на вопрос, иначе говоря, которые его хорошо понимают, способны правильно оценить является ли вопрос точным дубликатом или нет.

В комментарии к своему вопросу вы можете спросить участника, указавшего дубликат, что он думает о существующем ответе у другого вопроса.

Я думаю, можно в подсказке, **при голосовании за закрытие вопроса как дубликат, потребовать наличия рабочего (по мнению голосующего) ответа**—чтобы более явно намерение уже присутствующее в системе передать. Если есть желание, вы можете отдельное обсуждение начать специально об этом, чтобы ещё больше уменьшить вероятность, что вопрос будет закрыт как дубликат, не имея подходящего решения.

Comment: _система не позволяет пометить вопрос как оригинал, если у него нет положительного ответа._ - на самом деле позволяет пометить даже вопрос вообще без ответа. не знаю с чем это может быть связано

Comment: @Grundy верно. Система требует наличие ответа. Поправил.

Comment: не не, я как раз говорю, что это не так: _В оригинальном вопросе должен быть хотя бы один ответ. Вопрос без ответа не может быть отмечен как оригинал дубликата._ Система **позволяет**, иногда, не знаю от чего зависит, указать оригинал **вообще без ответа**.

Comment: @Grundy: если вы заметили, что сайт ведёт себя не так как задокументировано, то это баг (или в движке или в документации)—стоит отдельное обсуждение открыть.

Comment: Я почти уверен, уже было какое-то обсуждение по этому поводу.

Comment: Наличие непринятых ответов, не гарантирует решение проблемы, поставленной в вопросе, поэтому утверждение является ложным в названии кнопки.

Comment: @edem **ничто** не гарантирует решение вашей проблемы. То что ответ принят не значит что это правильный ответ, то что ответ имеет положительные голоса не значит что это правильный ответ. Но одни исходы более вероятны чем другие. Надпись на кнопке не может быть ложной—это вопрос к вам адресованный, поэтому там **две** опции (помог/не помог)—ещё раз: если это не решило проблему, то  выбирайте *вторую* опцию в интерфейсе: отредактируйте вопрос, указав как конкретно ответ не работает (как обычно: что ожидали получить, что вместо этого происходит, минимальный полный пример кода итд)

Comment: А если это **не решило** проблему, но тем не менее автор согласен с тем, что вопросы идентичны/похожи/дубликаты, зачем ему выбирать второй вариант, чтобы отредактировать вопрос? Тут и так понятно, что **нужно** нажимать кнопку с ложным предположением.

Comment: @edem: не имеет значения насколько вы думаете вопросы похожи или нет. Нас интересуют только **точные** дубликаты (точность определяется идентичностью **решений**). Используйте здравый смысл: какое действие поможет решить вашу задачу *и* улучшит сайт. Если решение не работает, то (третий раз повторяю) *редактируйте* ваш вопрос, указав как именно подробно ответ не подходит в вашем случае. Иногда более новый вопрос может стать оригиналом, если он содержит лучшую формулировку и/или лучшие ответы (если действительно ответы для вашего и предложенного вопросов совпадают).

Comment: Если по Вашему мнению для системы "не имеет значения насколько вы думаете вопросы похожи или нет" и тем не менее она даёт выбор из двух действий, то мне это напоминает опрос с вариантами ответов: 1) Да, не против. 2) Нет, не против. Поэтому мне нет смысла редактировать вопрос когда есть подобный, заданный ранее, и который хоть и имеет ответ, но решения не имеет, а система говорит, что мол "Это решило мою проблему". Так что по данному вопросу у меня всё, основные аргументы, на мой взгляд, я указал.

Comment: @Grundy потестировал закрытие, используя оригинал без ответа. Система работает как задокументировано (и как я помню она работала). Если для вас работает не так, то задайте новый вопрос на Мете.

Comment: @jfs, да, надо будет поймать момент. Я тоже успел попробовать и тоже сработало как ожидалось. Но в чате PashPash, Тоже говорил что _можно закрывать_

Comment: @edem: Я не понимаю, что вы не понимаете. С чем вы не согласны? Я вам говорю: не нажимайте на кнопку: "это решило проблему", если для вас проблему это не решило. С этим согласны? В чём проблемы с выбором второй опции? Вы думаете что другой вопрос идентичен вашему даже если его ответ не работает в вашем случае? Для простоты: допустим что вопросы идентичны по вашему мнению, существующий ответ для вас не работает. Мое предложение: отредактируйте вопрос, укажите, что вы думаете ответ не работает, что вопросы иначе одинаковые. Наличие  живого автора позволит ответ найти и сделать вопрос оригиналом.

Comment: "Я вам говорю: не нажимайте на кнопку: "это решило проблему", если для вас проблему это не решило. С этим согласны?" - так суть в кнопке состоит в том, что если её нажать, вопрос будет помечен как дубликат другого вопроса с ответами (принятыми или нет). Хотя, они, эти ответы, могут проблему и не решать, и тем не меннее автор вопрос может согласится с тем, что его вопрос похож на другой и нажать эту кнопку, чтобы все ответы по этой теме адресовывались основному вопросу.

Comment: Т.е. **нажатие кнопки**, как мне думается, говорит о том, что **автор согласен с тем, что его вопрос похож на другой**, а не о том, что в том другом вопросе непосредственно имеет **рабочее** решение, а ответы да, могут быть, даже и заплюсованные, но **не рабочие**.

Comment: @edem: нет. Вы причину со следствием путаете. Если кто-то предложил вопрос-дубликат, значит кто-то думает, что его ответы будут ответы и для вашего вопроса. Если вы согласны, то есть если "это решило проблему", **тогда и только тогда** (`iff`) вопрос можно рассматривать дубликатом. Назначение этой кнопки (причина её существования), чтобы не дожидаться 5 голосов (или сколько нужно), а закрыть вопрос сразу. Если решения нет (независимо от причины), то не следует вопрос закрывать, не думая полезно ли это. Даже если позже окажется, что действительно вопросы являются дубликатами...

Comment: ..не следует их закрывать пока решения не найдено. Какой вопрос выбрать оригиналом, а какой дубликатом позже можно будет решить (порядок создания, это один из факторов, но другие такие как ясность формулировки, её популярность в запросах из поисковика, наличие хороших ответов могут большее значение иметь)

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4001/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ad%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b5#comment13169_4004